# ¿Es mejor usar los using dentro del namespace?

Tags: c#

En el trabajo nos sugirieron usar los usings dentro del namespace.

```
namespace Functions.ProcessBatches.Transfers.Business
{
    using AutoMapper;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using System.Security.Principal;

    public class Ejemplo{
    }
}
```

a diferencia de:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace Functions.ProcessBatches.Transfers.Business
{
    public class Ejemplo{
    }
}
```

Pregunté pero sólo me dijeron que son 'buenas practicas' encerrar los using en el namespace. ¿Alguien podría dar una explicación mas detallada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En muchos casos da igual, pero si metes tus using dentro del namespace, el compilador va a buscar primero esos using.

Ejemplo...

En un archivo tienes esto:

```
using System;
namespace Namespace1.SubNamespace
{
    public class Foo
    {
        private void Algo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

Y en otro archivo tienes esto (no tiene ningún using):

```
namespace Namespace1
{
    public class Console
    {
    }
}
```

El compilador va a buscar primero Namespace1 antes que el System del using, y va a encontrar Namespace1.Console y no System.Console. Obvio Namespace1.Console no tiene ningún método WriteLine.

Si cambias el primer archivo a:

```
namespace Namespace1.SubNamespace
{
    using System;
    public class Foo
    {
        private void Algo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

El compilador va a encontrar primero a System.Console.